# Gridviewscroll fails for long content. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

I am working on a project where I am creating tables from files. At times the data in the frozen cell is very long (longer than the grid size). I have it wrapped and showing correctly but when I use the gridviewscroll.js (http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/) the wrapping goes away and the text is stretched out. How can I fix this? in gridviewscroll.js I tried:

1. Commenting out this.Contentfixed.style.width
2. hard coding this.Contentfixed.style.width to 200 px (for example).

Nothing worked. How can I fix this issue?

Gridviewscroll.js code below:

```
    var GridViewScrollOptions = /** @class */ (function () {
    function GridViewScrollOptions() {
    }
    return GridViewScrollOptions;
}());
var GridViewScrollScrollPosition = /** @class */ (function () {
    function GridViewScrollScrollPosition() {
    }
    return GridViewScrollScrollPosition;
}());
var GridViewScroll = /** @class */ (function () {
    function GridViewScroll(options) {
        this._initialized = false;
        if (options.elementID == null)
            options.elementID = "";
        if (options.width == null)
            options.width = "700";
        if (options.height == null)
            options.height = "350";
        if (options.freezeColumnCssClass == null)
            options.freezeColumnCssClass = "";
        if (options.freezeFooterCssClass == null)
            options.freezeFooterCssClass = "";
        if (options.freezeHeaderRowCount == null)
            options.freezeHeaderRowCount = 1;
        if (options.freezeColumnCount == null)
            options.freezeColumnCount = 1;
        this.initializeOptions(options);
    }
    GridViewScroll.prototype.initializeOptions = function (options) {
        this.GridID = options.elementID;
        this.GridWidth = options.width;
        this.GridHeight = options.height;
        this.FreezeColumn = options.freezeColumn;
        this.FreezeFooter = options.freezeFooter;
        this.FreezeColumnCssClass = options.freezeColumnCssClass;
        this.FreezeFooterCssClass = options.freezeFooterCssClass;
        this.FreezeHeaderRowCount = options.freezeHeaderRowCount;
        this.FreezeColumnCount = options.freezeColumnCount;
        this.OnScroll = options.onscroll;
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.enhance = function () {
        this.FreezeCellWidths = [];
        this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled = false;
        this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled = false;
        if (this.GridID == null || this.GridID == "") {
            return;
        }
        this.ContentGrid = document.getElementById(this.GridID);
        if (this.ContentGrid == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.ContentGrid.rows.length < 2) {
            return;
        }
        if (this._initialized) {
            this.undo();
        }
        this._initialized = true;
        this.Parent = this.ContentGrid.parentNode;
        this.ContentGrid.style.display = "none";
        if (typeof this.GridWidth == 'string' && this.GridWidth.indexOf("%") > -1) {
            var percentage = parseInt(this.GridWidth);
            this.Width = this.Parent.offsetWidth * percentage / 100;
        }
        else {
            this.Width = parseInt(this.GridWidth);
        }
        if (typeof this.GridHeight == 'string' && this.GridHeight.indexOf("%") > -1) {
            var percentage = parseInt(this.GridHeight);
            this.Height = this.Parent.offsetHeight * percentage / 100;
        }
        else {
            this.Height = parseInt(this.GridHeight);
        }
        this.ContentGrid.style.display = "";
        this.ContentGridHeaderRows = this.getGridHeaderRows();
        this.ContentGridItemRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(this.FreezeHeaderRowCount);
        var footerIndex = this.ContentGrid.rows.length - 1;
        this.ContentGridFooterRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(footerIndex);
        this.Content = document.createElement('div');
        this.Content.id = this.GridID + "_Content";
        this.Content.style.position = "relative";
        this.Content = this.Parent.insertBefore(this.Content, this.ContentGrid);
        this.ContentFixed = document.createElement('div');
        this.ContentFixed.id = this.GridID + "_Content_Fixed";
        this.ContentFixed.style.overflow = "auto";
        this.ContentFixed = this.Content.appendChild(this.ContentFixed);
        this.ContentGrid = this.ContentFixed.appendChild(this.ContentGrid);
        this.ContentFixed.style.width = String(this.Width) + "px";
        if (this.ContentGrid.offsetWidth > this.Width) {
            this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled = true;
        }
        if (this.ContentGrid.offsetHeight > this.Height) {
            this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled = true;
        }
        this.Header = document.createElement('div');
        this.Header.id = this.GridID + "_Header";
        this.Header.style.position = "relative";
        this.HeaderFixed = document.createElement('div');
        this.HeaderFixed.id = this.GridID + "_Header_Fixed";
        this.HeaderFixed.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.Header = this.Parent.insertBefore(this.Header, this.Content);
        this.HeaderFixed = this.Header.appendChild(this.HeaderFixed);
        this.ScrollbarWidth = this.getScrollbarWidth();
        this.prepareHeader();
        this.calculateHeader();
        this.Header.style.width = String(this.Width) + "px";
        if (this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled) {
            this.HeaderFixed.style.width = String(this.Width - this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
            if (this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {
                this.ContentFixed.style.width = this.HeaderFixed.style.width;
                if (this.isRTL()) {
                    this.ContentFixed.style.paddingLeft = String(this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
                }
                else {
                    this.ContentFixed.style.paddingRight = String(this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
                }
            }
            this.ContentFixed.style.height = String(this.Height - this.Header.offsetHeight) + "px";
        }
        else {
            this.HeaderFixed.style.width = this.Header.style.width;
            this.ContentFixed.style.width = this.Header.style.width;
        }
        if (this.FreezeColumn && this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {
            this.appendFreezeHeader();
            this.appendFreezeContent();
        }
        if (this.FreezeFooter && this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled) {
            this.appendFreezeFooter();
            if (this.FreezeColumn && this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {
                this.appendFreezeFooterColumn();
            }
        }
        var self = this;
        this.ContentFixed.onscroll = function (event) {
            var scrollTop = self.ContentFixed.scrollTop;
            var scrollLeft = self.ContentFixed.scrollLeft;
            self.HeaderFixed.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
            if (self.ContentFreeze != null)
                self.ContentFreeze.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            if (self.FooterFreeze != null)
                self.FooterFreeze.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
            if (self.OnScroll != null) {
                self.OnScroll(scrollTop, scrollLeft);
            }
        };
    };
    Object.defineProperty(GridViewScroll.prototype, "scrollPosition", {
        get: function () {
            var position = new GridViewScrollScrollPosition();
            position.scrollTop = this.ContentFixed.scrollTop;
            position.scrollLeft = this.ContentFixed.scrollLeft;
            return position;
        },
        set: function (gridViewScrollScrollPosition) {
            var scrollTop = gridViewScrollScrollPosition.scrollTop;
            var scrollLeft = gridViewScrollScrollPosition.scrollLeft;
            this.ContentFixed.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            this.ContentFixed.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
            if (this.ContentFreeze != null)
                this.ContentFreeze.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            if (this.FooterFreeze != null)
                this.FooterFreeze.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    GridViewScroll.prototype.getGridHeaderRows = function () {
        var gridHeaderRows = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.FreezeHeaderRowCount; i++) {
            gridHeaderRows.push(this.ContentGrid.rows.item(i));
        }
        return gridHeaderRows;
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.prepareHeader = function () {
        this.HeaderGrid = this.ContentGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.HeaderGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Header_Fixed_Grid";
        this.HeaderGrid = this.HeaderFixed.appendChild(this.HeaderGrid);
        this.prepareHeaderGridRows();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.length; i++) {
            this.appendHelperElement(this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(i));
            this.appendHelperElement(this.HeaderGridHeaderCells[i]);
        }
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.prepareHeaderGridRows = function () {
        this.HeaderGridHeaderRows = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.FreezeHeaderRowCount; i++) {
            var gridHeaderRow = this.ContentGridHeaderRows[i];
            var headerGridHeaderRow = gridHeaderRow.cloneNode(true);
            this.HeaderGridHeaderRows.push(headerGridHeaderRow);
            this.HeaderGrid.appendChild(headerGridHeaderRow);
        }
        this.prepareHeaderGridCells();
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.prepareHeaderGridCells = function () {
        this.HeaderGridHeaderCells = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.length; i++) {
            for (var rowIndex in this.HeaderGridHeaderRows) {
                var cgridHeaderRow = this.HeaderGridHeaderRows[rowIndex];
                var fixedCellIndex = 0;
                for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cgridHeaderRow.cells.length; cellIndex++) {
                    var cgridHeaderCell = cgridHeaderRow.cells.item(cellIndex);
                    if (cgridHeaderCell.colSpan == 1 && i == fixedCellIndex) {
                        this.HeaderGridHeaderCells.push(cgridHeaderCell);
                    }
                    else {
                        fixedCellIndex += cgridHeaderCell.colSpan - 1;
                    }
                    fixedCellIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.calculateHeader = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.length; i++) {
            var gridItemCell = this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(i);
            var helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
            var helperWidth = parseInt(String(helperElement.offsetWidth));
            this.FreezeCellWidths.push(helperWidth);
            helperElement.style.width = helperWidth + "px";
            helperElement = this.HeaderGridHeaderCells[i].firstChild;
            helperElement.style.width = helperWidth + "px";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.FreezeHeaderRowCount; i++) {
            this.ContentGridHeaderRows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendFreezeHeader = function () {
        this.HeaderFreeze = document.createElement('div');
        this.HeaderFreeze.id = this.GridID + "_Header_Freeze";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.position = "absolute";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.top = "0px";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.left = "0px";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.width = "";
        this.HeaderFreezeGrid = this.HeaderGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.HeaderFreezeGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Header_Freeze_Grid";
        this.HeaderFreezeGrid = this.HeaderFreeze.appendChild(this.HeaderFreezeGrid);
        this.HeaderFreezeGridHeaderRows = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.HeaderGridHeaderRows.length; i++) {
            var headerFreezeGridHeaderRow = this.HeaderGridHeaderRows[i].cloneNode(false);
            this.HeaderFreezeGridHeaderRows.push(headerFreezeGridHeaderRow);
            var columnIndex = 0;
            var columnCount = 0;
            while (columnCount < this.FreezeColumnCount) {
                var freezeColumn = this.HeaderGridHeaderRows[i].cells.item(columnIndex).cloneNode(true);
                headerFreezeGridHeaderRow.appendChild(freezeColumn);
                columnCount += freezeColumn.colSpan;
                columnIndex++;
            }
            this.HeaderFreezeGrid.appendChild(headerFreezeGridHeaderRow);
        }
        this.HeaderFreeze = this.Header.appendChild(this.HeaderFreeze);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendFreezeContent = function () {
        this.ContentFreeze = document.createElement('div');
        this.ContentFreeze.id = this.GridID + "_Content_Freeze";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.position = "absolute";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.top = "0px";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.left = "0px";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.width = "";
        this.ContentFreezeGrid = this.HeaderGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.ContentFreezeGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Content_Freeze_Grid";
        this.ContentFreezeGrid = this.ContentFreeze.appendChild(this.ContentFreezeGrid);
        var freezeCellHeights = [];
        var paddingTop = this.getPaddingTop(this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(0));
        var paddingBottom = this.getPaddingBottom(this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(0));
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGrid.rows.length; i++) {
            var gridItemRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(i);
            var gridItemCell = gridItemRow.cells.item(0);
            var helperElement = void 0;
            if (gridItemCell.firstChild.className == "gridViewScrollHelper") {
                helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
            }
            else {
                helperElement = this.appendHelperElement(gridItemCell);
            }
            var helperHeight = parseInt(String(gridItemCell.offsetHeight - paddingTop - paddingBottom));
            freezeCellHeights.push(helperHeight);
            var cgridItemRow = gridItemRow.cloneNode(false);
            var cgridItemCell = gridItemCell.cloneNode(true);
            if (this.FreezeColumnCssClass != null || this.FreezeColumnCssClass != "")
                cgridItemRow.className = this.FreezeColumnCssClass;
            var columnIndex = 0;
            var columnCount = 0;
            while (columnCount < this.FreezeColumnCount) {
                var freezeColumn = gridItemRow.cells.item(columnIndex).cloneNode(true);
                cgridItemRow.appendChild(freezeColumn);
                columnCount += freezeColumn.colSpan;
                columnIndex++;
            }
            this.ContentFreezeGrid.appendChild(cgridItemRow);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGrid.rows.length; i++) {
            var gridItemRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(i);
            var gridItemCell = gridItemRow.cells.item(0);
            var cgridItemRow = this.ContentFreezeGrid.rows.item(i);
            var cgridItemCell = cgridItemRow.cells.item(0);
            var helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
            helperElement.style.height = String(freezeCellHeights[i]) + "px";
            helperElement = cgridItemCell.firstChild;
            helperElement.style.height = String(freezeCellHeights[i]) + "px";
        }
        if (this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled) {
            this.ContentFreeze.style.height = String(this.Height - this.Header.offsetHeight - this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
        }
        else {
            this.ContentFreeze.style.height = String(this.ContentFixed.offsetHeight - this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
        }
        this.ContentFreeze = this.Content.appendChild(this.ContentFreeze);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendFreezeFooter = function () {
        this.FooterFreeze = document.createElement('div');
        this.FooterFreeze.id = this.GridID + "_Footer_Freeze";
        this.FooterFreeze.style.position = "absolute";
        this.FooterFreeze.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.FooterFreeze.style.left = "0px";
        this.FooterFreeze.style.width = String(this.ContentFixed.offsetWidth - this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
        this.FooterFreezeGrid = this.HeaderGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.FooterFreezeGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Footer_Freeze_Grid";
        this.FooterFreezeGrid = this.FooterFreeze.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeGrid);
        this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow = this.ContentGridFooterRow.cloneNode(true);
        if (this.FreezeFooterCssClass != null || this.FreezeFooterCssClass != "")
            this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.className = this.FreezeFooterCssClass;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.cells.length; i++) {
            var cgridHeaderCell = this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.cells.item(i);
            var helperElement = this.appendHelperElement(cgridHeaderCell);
            helperElement.style.width = String(this.FreezeCellWidths[i]) + "px";
        }
        this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow = this.FooterFreezeGrid.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow);
        this.FooterFreeze = this.Content.appendChild(this.FooterFreeze);
        var footerFreezeTop = this.ContentFixed.offsetHeight - this.FooterFreeze.offsetHeight;
        if (this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {
            footerFreezeTop -= this.ScrollbarWidth;
        }
        this.FooterFreeze.style.top = String(footerFreezeTop) + "px";
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendFreezeFooterColumn = function () {
        this.FooterFreezeColumn = document.createElement('div');
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.id = this.GridID + "_Footer_FreezeColumn";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.position = "absolute";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.left = "0px";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.width = "";
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid = this.HeaderGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Footer_FreezeColumn_Grid";
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid = this.FooterFreezeColumn.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid);
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow = this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.cloneNode(false);
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow = this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow);
        if (this.FreezeFooterCssClass != null)
            this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow.className = this.FreezeFooterCssClass;
        var columnIndex = 0;
        var columnCount = 0;
        while (columnCount < this.FreezeColumnCount) {
            var freezeColumn = this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.cells.item(columnIndex).cloneNode(true);
            this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow.appendChild(freezeColumn);
            columnCount += freezeColumn.colSpan;
            columnIndex++;
        }
        var footerFreezeTop = this.ContentFixed.offsetHeight - this.FooterFreeze.offsetHeight;
        if (this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {
            footerFreezeTop -= this.ScrollbarWidth;
        }
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.top = String(footerFreezeTop) + "px";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn = this.Content.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeColumn);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendHelperElement = function (gridItemCell) {
        var helperElement = document.createElement('div');
        helperElement.className = "gridViewScrollHelper";
        while (gridItemCell.hasChildNodes()) {
            helperElement.appendChild(gridItemCell.firstChild);
        }
        return gridItemCell.appendChild(helperElement);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.getScrollbarWidth = function () {
        var innerElement = document.createElement('p');
        innerElement.style.width = "100%";
        innerElement.style.height = "200px";
        var outerElement = document.createElement('div');
        outerElement.style.position = "absolute";
        outerElement.style.top = "0px";
        outerElement.style.left = "0px";
        outerElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
        outerElement.style.width = "200px";
        outerElement.style.height = "150px";
        outerElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
        outerElement.appendChild(innerElement);
        document.body.appendChild(outerElement);
        var innerElementWidth = innerElement.offsetWidth;
        outerElement.style.overflow = 'scroll';
        var outerElementWidth = innerElement.offsetWidth;
        if (innerElementWidth === outerElementWidth)
            outerElementWidth = outerElement.clientWidth;
        document.body.removeChild(outerElement);
        return innerElementWidth - outerElementWidth;
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.isRTL = function () {
        var direction = "";
        if (window.getComputedStyle) {
            direction = window.getComputedStyle(this.ContentGrid, null).getPropertyValue('direction');
        }
        else {
            direction = this.ContentGrid.currentStyle.direction;
        }
        return direction === "rtl";
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.getPaddingTop = function (element) {
        var value = "";
        if (window.getComputedStyle) {
            value = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('padding-Top');
        }
        else {
            value = element.currentStyle.paddingTop;
        }
        return parseInt(value);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.getPaddingBottom = function (element) {
        var value = "";
        if (window.getComputedStyle) {
            value = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('padding-Bottom');
        }
        else {
            value = element.currentStyle.paddingBottom;
        }
        return parseInt(value);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.undo = function () {
        this.undoHelperElement();
        for (var _i = 0, _a = this.ContentGridHeaderRows; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
            var contentGridHeaderRow = _a[_i];
            contentGridHeaderRow.style.display = "";
        }
        this.Parent.insertBefore(this.ContentGrid, this.Header);
        this.Parent.removeChild(this.Header);
        this.Parent.removeChild(this.Content);
        this._initialized = false;
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.undoHelperElement = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.length; i++) {
            var gridItemCell = this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(i);
            var helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
            while (helperElement.hasChildNodes()) {
                gridItemCell.appendChild(helperElement.firstChild);
            }
            gridItemCell.removeChild(helperElement);
        }
        if (this.FreezeColumn) {
            for (var i = 2; i < this.ContentGrid.rows.length; i++) {
                var gridItemRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(i);
                var gridItemCell = gridItemRow.cells.item(0);
                var helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
                while (helperElement.hasChildNodes()) {
                    gridItemCell.appendChild(helperElement.firstChild);
                }
                gridItemCell.removeChild(helperElement);
            }
        }
    };
    return GridViewScroll;
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. in my html I added the max-width parameter. When I added this to the CSS it was ignoring it but when I added it directly in the html it worked.

```
 <td style="max-width:190px; min-width:50px;">@data[column].ToString()</td>
```